# Using Images for Points in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I'm using `ListPlot` to label a sequence of ordered pairs in $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$:

> [image]

**Question:** How can I make these points show up as images (from the web, etc) instead of as blue dots? I'd like to keep the "Callout" labels if possible, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Just use `PlotMarkers` like you normally would. There are examples in the documentation for `PlotMarkers` where they use images.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{1, 1}, {4, 4}};
labels = {"A","B"};
images = Rasterize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}], 
    RasterSize -> 200, ImageSize -> 30]&/@ {"Lena","Apples"};
```

Using `images` as plot markers (as in Rohit's answer) is the most straightforward approach. Here are a few additional ways:

**ListPlot with nested Callouts:**

You can use the image as one of multiple call-outs for each data point:

```
data2 = MapThread[Callout[Callout[#, #3, Automatic, 1, 
      LeaderSize -> {{40, 45 Degree, 20}, 20}, Appearance -> "Leader"], #2, Center] &, 
    {data, images, labels}];

ListPlot[data2,  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 2]
```

[image]

**ListPlot + Callout + Labeled:**

You can use `Labeled` to inject the image as a label:

```
data3 = MapThread[{Callout[Labeled[#, #2, Center], #3, Automatic, 1, 
        LeaderSize -> {{40, 45 Degree, 20}, 20}, Appearance -> "Leader"]} &, 
     {data, images, labels}];

ListPlot[data3,  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 2]
```

[image]

**BubbleChart + ChartElements:**

```
BubbleChart[Append[#, 1]& /@ data,
  ChartElements -> images,
  ChartLabels -> Callout[labels, Above], 
  PlotRangePadding -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: What are the advantages to this approach?

Comment: @George, the only important advantage I can think of is you can inject additional information into visualization using the third components of input data (taken as 1 for both data points in the example)  that control the relative bubble sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Using `PlotMarkers` as @C.E. suggested and images from @kglr

```
images = Rasterize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}], 
    RasterSize -> 200, ImageSize -> 30]&/@ {"Lena","Apples"};

ListPlot[{{Callout[{0.8, 0.8}, "A", Above]}, {Callout[{-0.8, -0.8}, 
    "B", Above]}}, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> images, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.25, 1.25}, {-1.25, 1.25}}]
```

[image]